# select two balance team of two people

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, plpgsql

I want to make a balance two teams with two people depending on their type and score.

Sample data

| type | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 76 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 70 |

Expected result

| type | score | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 76 | 1 |
| 2 | 60 | 1 |
| 1 | 55 | 2 |
| 2 | 70 | 2 |